# Mac dual boot fail to read ubuntu12.10 usb stick

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, usb, macbook-pro

I have a late 2011 macbook pro.

Partitioned off 40 gigs using the disk utility app.

I have the rEFInd Boot manager correctly installed.

Followed [ubuntu's](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) usb stick disk image instructions.

Checked the image using md5sum and got the correct hash back, the ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.iso.

When I restart, it brings me to rEFInd's menu. There's a grub and a root usb stick options as well as the osx partition and the empty partition intended for ubuntu. If I go to the empty partition, there are doubles of the root and grub options.

They all bring me to a same grub screen. When I try any of the options my screen goes black. When I'm trying the "install ubuntu" option, I hear the chime after ~20 seconds, but then the screen continues to go black.

Considering that it was a graphics issue, I changed my resolution to 800x600 while in osx then restarted, I'm not sure if those settings would carry over as rEFInd seems to default to the highest resolution possible (1680x1050).

Any theories or tips? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Macs can't boot from USB sticks.
you should try burning an .ISO to a DVD, you can find instructions at: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-dvd-on-mac-osx.
Hope this helped, it worked for me!